# Running an once-a-day autoupdater thread in a Dash app

Tags: plotly-dash

I have a Dash app with a standard layout which I run with standard invocation:

```
#wsgi.py

from __init__ import app
from __init__ import server

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(port=5000, debug = True)
```

I would like to run a once-a-day updater script for some calculations with a general schematic like this:

```
#one of the application pages .py

def update_df_daily_loop():
    while True:
        if time since last update > 24h:
            run update
            last updated = now
        else:
            sleep for 15 minutes

#tried invoking the thread like this - but it blocks the server from starting
thread0 = threading.Thread(target=update_df_daily_loop)
thread0.start()
thread0.join()
```

Where should I put the invokation? If I just run it as a thread it blocks the server from ever starting.

Comment: Why not using a cron job that triggers the sript daily ?

Comment: The output displays in a form on the site. I could run a separate script to just do the calc (adding results to the database) - but I would need to restart the website to pull the latest numbers from the database every day. I just haven't figured out a way to avoid doing that, otherwise if there is a way to make it work, would be cool to use a cron job

Comment: It depends how your app consumes data. Supposing it can load the latest data from db (updated calc), and put these data in a global variable, by using a specific route callback you could also update that variable later on : so the cron job would first update the db, and then make a http request to that specific route in order to trigger the app callback, and the callback would pull the latest calc and update the variable accordingly.